# Blank MapView on Android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I implemented an Android app a year ago using Google Maps v1, and now I need to fix a bug. The problem is, when I run the app from Eclipse on my hardware device the map is blank. In LogCat I get the error:

```
04-26 14:07:30.754: W/System.err(2354):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
```

I think this is an API key error, but over the past 2 days of searching Stack Overflow, Google and the Maps SDK website, I can't find a solution. Although this problem is addressed on Stack Overflow already, none of the solutions have worked for me. Hopefully some experienced person can help me out.

I know that Maps v1 is deprecated, and I intend to upgrade to v2. But right now I just need to get this bug fixed, and according to Google the existing API keys should continue to work.

One thing to note is that I recently moved my development environment from my PC to a Mac, making sure to use the same `debug.keystore` file.  I'm not sure if this is a red herring, but perhaps there is some setting or file I need to copy over from the old environment.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

1. Checked the debug.keystore file was identical to the one on my old computer.
2. Tried to check my API key is correct on the Google API Console, but it doesn't appear any more (probably because it's deprecated).
3. Registered new API key for Maps v2 and tried to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally figured it out. The default expiry for a debug certificate is 365 days, and mine expired Sep 09 2012. This means I have to upgrade to Google Maps v2 to fix this bug, and I am absolutely spitting tacks, because this means I can no longer support Android 1.6 but will be forced to a minimum version of 2.2.  This will cut out 8% of my users who can't upgrade due to fragmentation, and wasted 2 frustrating days of my time.

Why do Google make it so hard to use their maps on their own platform (Android)? It's so easy to create Google Maps apps for iOS in comparison.  Although perhaps they are attempting to address this fragmentation with the Google Play SDK which can be downloaded independently of the Android version?  Anyway, I am about to find out because my hand is being forced.

Grrr!

Answer (score 0):

There may be several other reasons.

1.) If you are using java 1.7 or above you have to generate md5 Print in different way as normally it always return sh1 key. Use -v switch like.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -v -list -alias
androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

2.) Internet permission required in Android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
 </uses-permission>
 <uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
 </uses-permission>
```

3.) Use following permission in Manifest file.

```
 <!-- import the library com.google.android.maps!!! -->
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer:
1. But I can't regenerate this key, because it's deprecated. Right?
2. I already have this.
3. I already have this.

The weird thing is, this used to work!

Comment: What is deperecated here.? Is that debug.keystore or what?

Comment: The Google Maps for Android v1 is now deprecated in favour of v2. You can no longer apply for v1 API keys, but of course I already have one. Google say that the v1 keys will continue to work, but that you can't get new ones. The v1 API key was generated from the debug.keystore, which is why I made sure to copy it over from the old system.